# How to initialize all variables from a namespace in one class

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am making a small game using SFML.
I want to load all my resources in one go when the game launches, so every time a new entity is created new resources don't need to be loaded to memory slowing down the game.

I have made a header file with a namespace for each kind of resource I need:

```
#pragma once

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <iostream>

#include "spritesheet.h"

namespace PlayerSprite {
    extern Spritesheet playerSpritesheet;
    extern sf::Sprite sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, sp5, sp6;
    extern int width = 16;
    extern int height = 16;
}

namespace ButtonSprite {
    extern Spritesheet buttonSpritesheet;
    extern sf::Sprite button;
    extern int width = 32;
    extern int height = 16;
}

class Resources {
    public:
        Resources() = default;
        void loadResources();
};
```

Now I don't know much about namespaces only very basic stuff, this is the first reason to use one.

Now in the cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "../headers/resources.h"

void Resources::loadResources() {
    // PLAYER
    PlayerSprite::playerSpritesheet.setSprite("./res/img/tiles.png");
    PlayerSprite::sp1 = PlayerSprite::playerSpritesheet.getSprite(0, 0, PlayerSprite::width, 
    PlayerSprite::height);
    PlayerSprite::sp2 = PlayerSprite::playerSpritesheet.getSprite(32, 0, PlayerSprite::width, 
    PlayerSprite::height);
    PlayerSprite::sp3 = PlayerSprite::playerSpritesheet.getSprite(48, 0, PlayerSprite::width, 
    PlayerSprite::height);
    PlayerSprite::sp4 = PlayerSprite::playerSpritesheet.getSprite(64, 0, PlayerSprite::width, 
    PlayerSprite::height);
    PlayerSprite::sp5 = PlayerSprite::playerSpritesheet.getSprite(80, 0, PlayerSprite::width, 
    PlayerSprite::height);
    PlayerSprite::sp6 = PlayerSprite::playerSpritesheet.getSprite(0, 16, PlayerSprite::width, 
    PlayerSprite::height);
    // PLAYER

    // BUTTONS
    ButtonSprite::buttonSpritesheet.setSprite("./res/img/tiles.png");
    ButtonSprite::button = ButtonSprite::buttonSpritesheet.getSprite(48, 16, 32, 16);
    // BUTTONS
}
```

I then call this function in the main game file, but when I run I get this error in the player class:

`undefined reference to 'PlayerSprite:sp1'`

I don't know if this is because of the namespace declaration, or me coding the system wrong.

---

After looking at some comments on this question I have added this:

```
void Resources::allocateStorage() {
    sf::Sprite PlayerSprite::spritesheet;
    sf::Sprite PlayerSprite::sp1;
}
```

In the cpp file, but I am now getting this error:

`unqualified-id in declaration before ';' token` on the 1st line after the implementation of the function.

Comment: I think `PlayerSprite` and `ButtonSprite` really want to become classes. Maybe with common base.

Comment: You still need to tell the compiler to allocate space for them somewhere. Before your `loadResources()` function, you would need to do: `sf::Sprite PlayerSpriter::sp1;` (for each variable)

Comment: @Brian, yes, but judging by the error, and the fact they're all marked `extern`, it seems like they aren't ever allocated any space. So when trying to initialize, they don't actually exist in memory.

Comment: @ChrisMM I see what you meant now. I'll delete my previous comment.

Comment: @ChrisMM The reason i used `extern` is because when I was looking into namespaces I saw about using `extern` when declaring a variable in a namespace.

Comment: @TylerHarrison, there's no program with using `extern`, but they still need to allocate space.

Comment: @ChrisMM I have tried your comment, and have updated the question ^

Comment: You may find [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files) helpful. `extern` essentially tells the compiler that the symbol you're declaring is going to be _defined somewhere else_, which will need to be located at link time. Since you never define the symbols you declared as `extern`, the linker is complaining that it cannot find suitable definitions.

Comment: @ChrisMM Arrgh! Yes, my bad

Comment: @TylerHarrison, not inside a function ;)

Comment: @ChrisMM I tried putting it in a constructor and got the same error

Comment: @TylerHarrison **outside** of any function/constructor/destructor/etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the variables are not actually defined anywhere, just declared. When using `extern`, the compiler will assume that this variable exists, so the compiler can continue on assuming that the variable exists. The linker will then come in, and see **where** that variable exists. If it does not, you get an undefined reference error. To fix this, you need to define the variables somewhere.

For example, in say `resources.cpp`, you would have:

```
#include "../headers/resources.h"

sf::Sprite PlayerSpriter::sp1;
sf::Sprite PlayerSpriter::sp2;
sf::Sprite PlayerSpriter::sp3;
// etc...


void Resources::loadResources() { 
    // …
}
```

This is in addition to what you already have in your header.

NOTE: From your edit, this would occur outside any function.